# Send custom response fields based on user inputs fields in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have one requirement, where user will send fields that he wants in response rather than entire JSON:

```
?fields=name,description
```

Basically i have employee JSON, which has many fields. But he wants only name and description. He can change it also with other fields. Later he can select other fields and send in request.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to access query params use `@RequestParam` annotation.

```
@GetMapping("/api/foos")
public String getFoos(@RequestParam String fields) {
    // ...
}
```

Variable `fields` will contain the complete string, so you'll have to split it by delimiter, e.g. by using `String.split`.

Then build the desired response format, if it's a flat structure you could use a Map<String, String>, which will be deserialized to a flat json object.

```
Map<String,String> response = new HashMap<>();
response.put("fieldName","value");
```

https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-split-a-string/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, this is a case to avoid over-fetching or under-fetching of data and also a good example for GraphQL API development. Once you develop the GraphQL API with the schema you will have fewer future change impacts. The client can fetch whatever fields needed
[Link for when to use graphql](https://www.contentstack.com/blog/tech-talk/why-and-when-to-use-graphql/)